# Converting a Tensorflow model to a frozen .pb graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, conv-neural-network

I have troubles by converting my trained SSD300 model (checkpoint, metagraph) in the frozen .pb format, which is required to run it via opencv without having tensorflow installed.

I use [this](https://github.com/HiKapok/SSD.TensorFlow/) SSD implementation, which works fine. I trained a model (checkpoint) on my own data set and the checkpoint can easily be restored as done in the demo script [simple_ssd_demo.py](https://github.com/HiKapok/SSD.TensorFlow/blob/master/simple_ssd_demo.py).

The first thing which I did was to freeze the graph using the script [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py). Maybe the problem was already there, since I was not sure by identifying the output node names required for keeping only that part of the graph which is needed for inference. However, I chose the node total_loss as the output node, since I did not find the 3 nodes representing the output variables labels_, scores_ and bboxes_.

```
labels_, scores_, bboxes_ = sess.run([all_labels, all_scores, all_bboxes], feed_dict = {image_input : np_image, shape_input : np_image.shape[:-1]})
```

Then I tried to import the frozen graph using

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(tfmodel_path+'frozen_graph.pb')
```

and I got an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testapp_Tensorflow.py", line 32, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(tfmodel_path+'frozen_graph.pb')
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:497:
    error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found: ssd300/conv4_3_scale/weights in function 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v10::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::connect'

[ WARN:0] terminating async callback
```

I don't understand why some weights are not found, since they are also needed to compute the loss.

What can I do for making the model readable for cv2.dnn ?

Comment: You should definitely **not** use the loss as the output node. To find the relevant output nodes, print all the nodes using `[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]` and search for it.

Comment: There are hundreds of names having sometimes similar names. Im am not sure which one I should use.